Give an example of a bounded function on $[0,1]$ which does not achieve its infimum on any $[a,b] \subset [0,1], a < b$.
Here is my attempt:
$f: [0,1] \rightarrow (0,1]$ with \begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
  x &\text{ if } x\not\in \mathbb{Q}\\
  \frac{1}{q} &\text{ if } x \neq 0, x \in \mathbb{Q}, x = \frac{p}{q}, p,q \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with }\gcd(p,q)=1\\
   1 &\text{ if } x = 0
 \end{cases}
\end{align}
Clearly, this is bounded between $0$ and $1$.
I claim that on any $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$, we have infimum $0$, which is unattainable. To prove this, I tried to take $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha > \beta, \gcd(\alpha, \beta) = 1$ and $[\frac{1}{\alpha},\frac{1}{\beta}] \subset [a,b]$, and construct a sequence of rational numbers in simplest form with increasing denominators, that converges to $\frac{1}{\beta}$. My argument for taking a subset interval with rational endpoints was that it would make constructing the sequence easier.
However, I am unable to construct such a sequence and likely there is a simpler way to do it.

Just note that for any interval, there are infinitely many $n$s, for which there is a $k$ such that  $k/n$ is in that interval.

Fix $a < b$. We can choose $q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/q < (b-a)$. Let $q_1$ be the smallest prime number larger than $q$, then there is some $p_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a < p_1 \cdot (1/q_1) < b$. Likewise, we let $q_2$ be the smallest prime number bigger than $q_1$, and so on.
Then, $f(p_n/q_n) = 1/q_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Also, I think your function can be simplified like this!
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1/q & \text{ if } x = p/q, \text{ $p$, $q$ relatively prime, and }x \neq 0 \\
1 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
